# How to save or export values of a variable in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

[new_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUWcW.png)

**Questions revised:
In my model, I have 10000 "Persons" as a type of agents at "Main" level. As shown new_Screenshot, there is a process like the statechart. "variable1" is determined by the process. For example, Person 1 will have 10 for the value of "variable1" while Person 2 will have 100 through the process. My question is how to obtain the values (e.g. Person 1: 10, Person 2: 100,.....Person 10000: 10) in AnyLogic.
Thank you.**

previous version: My model has 10000 "Persons" as a type of agents. "Persons" have a statechart and a variable ("variable1" in the Screenshot) obtains a set of different values from the statechart. I am trying to collect all those values from a variable for all 10000 "Persons". How can I do this? I have tried to use traceln but it didn't work because I need the values and not the min, max, average, etc.

Thank you!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDmSm.png)

Comment: your question is so badly phrased that it's impossible to understand it. the variable obtains a set of different values? What does that even mean? collect all those values? what values? And traceln doesn't give you min, max or average.... this question is nonsensical.... but anyways, if you want to collect values, i guess you need a collection

Comment: Felipe:: can you explain it more in detail? I also changed the question and the screenshot.

Comment: the answer to your question is
persons.get(N).variable1
Where N is any number between 0 and 9999

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is the following:

If your agent is defined as an agent type, then you can't create a population of 10,000... to create a population of 10,000 you need to create an agent population, so I assume that's what you did, even though you say the opposite.

An element of a population of agents can be accessed the same way as any collection using:
`persons.get(N);` where N is any integer between 0 and 9999.
If you want to access a variable in that particular agent:

```
persons.get(N).variable1
```